# How to dynamically call a generic method knowing only the string's name of a generic type parameter at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, generic-method, generic-type-parameters

I want to insert an object into my repository but not explicitly like that at coding-time:

```
_repository<Car>().Add(carObject);
```

Instead of this, I want to push the object to the corresponding class name at runtime.

I can create the object at runtime but I can't set the class name in `__repository<???>().Add(object)` here.

In this exemple, if I've a string name `Car` (it might be other class name like `Person`), then how can I do the same thing using the given code written only once to be applied to any type?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "Reflection".

Comment: @gunr2171 using reflection I can create the object in run time using reflection, that's fine, but how to set the class name in __repository<???>().Add(object) ??

Comment: Other comments actually answer your question, but you should not do that.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks given link works for me